# SSRS subtotal of row group and column group in matrix using InScope?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I am having trouble calculating a % of a parent row group within a column group, the expected result is like that below.

[image]

The percentage of column group is straight forward using the expression:

```
=Sum(Fields!Total.Value) / Sum(Fields!Total.Value, "LocationGroup")
```

Though I can't get an expression to work that would provide the subtotal for the intersection of `LocationGroup` and `CategoryGroup`.

I have acheived the desired results by modifying my dataset to calculate the subtotal using a `Window Function` in `TSQL` though I feel that this should also be achievable using an expression.

I've come across numerous articles that mention the `InScope` function though I haven't got this to work as expected.

Comment: Something like (pseudo code)  `IIF` `InScope("SubcategoryGroup")` then `Sum(Fields!Total.Value) / Sum(Fields!Total.Value, "CategoryGroup")` else `Sum(Fields!Total.Value) / Sum(Fields!Total.Value, "LocationGroup")` would do it I guess.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to calculate the total for the column group whenever you're in the `CategoryGroup` and if `SubcategoryGroup` is active you want to calculate the % within the `CategorygGroup`, so the following would achieve this in my opinion:

```
=IIF(InScope("SubcategoryGroup")
    ,Sum(Fields!Total.Value) / Sum(Fields!Total.Value, "CategoryGroup")
    ,Sum(Fields!Total.Value) / Sum(Fields!Total.Value, "LocationGroup")
    )
```

Comment: This gives the % of the entire `CategoryGroup` and not the intersection of `CategoryGroup` and `LocationGroup`. So the % for Subcategory A1 under Location A would return `12.5%` which is incorrect.